# Fragment interface call-back not storing passed values

Tags: java, android, interface

The interface

```
public interface GameSelectedListener {

public void onGameSelectedListener(int gameID, Boolean isCustom);
}
```

Inside FragmentA in the on attach I set the gameSelectedListener in on attach.

public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
super.onAttach(activity);

```
gameSelectedListener = (GameSelectedListener)activity;
```

}

In one part of the code some data is sent

```
gameSelectedListener.onGameSelectedListener(groupItems.get(groupPosition).iD, isCustom);
```

Main activity which implements the interface and calls a method in FragmentB

```
@Override
public void onGameSelectedListener(int gameID, Boolean isCustom) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub`enter code here`

    FB.setGameID(gameID, isCustom);


}
```

Inside Fragment B is the setGameID method which just sets some data inside that fragment.

```
public void setGameID(int gameID, Boolean isCustom)
{
        this.gameID = gameID;
        this.isCustom = isCustom;
}
```

With log statements (not shown here). The data generated by fragment A is successfully sent to main activity. I log the values of the variables in setGameID method of fragment B also appear correctly to that generated by fragment A.

**However here is the problem**

I get null pointer exceptions when using gameID and isCustom from the FragmentB. So I set some default values to check it and I noticed that the value change made in setGameID does not effect the global variables even though when logging the values in setGameID show the correct values. Note that these two variables are not changed anywhere else in the code. Just in setGameID method.

I don't know if this helps but my fragments are java fragments (not XML based) 
In main activity I create an instance of Fragment B in order to call setGameID. Note I declare this in the global area only.

```
FragmentB FB = new FragmentB();
```

Heres how it looks so far
Activity A -> Fragment Transaction add Fragment A -> From Fragment A Button click-> fragment replace  A with B

**EDIT** Added some more code: Issue could be here.

```
gameSelectedListener.onGameSelectedListener(groupItems.get(groupPosition).iD, isCustom);
fragment = FragmentB.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(Container.getId(), fragment, tag);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I think the problem could well be here because I invoke the listener and then make a the Fragment B instance. Could this be it?

Comment: are both fragments attached to the same activity?

Comment: Yes but the fragments are replaced through transactions. Heres how it looks so far Activity A -> Fragment Transaction add Fragment A -> From Fragment A Button click-> fragment replace A with B

Comment: and when does that happen

Comment: Here is the short version. When activity starts it adds Fragment A to a frame layout container. Inside fragment A is a list view which when any of the rows are pressed carries out a fragment transaction replace A with fragment B. This is where some confusion happens because many tutorials on inter fragment communication use XML fragments and not ones made In java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an EventBus instead of a listener! This design pattern mentioned in the official android docs is bullshit!

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

---

```
class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private int id;

    public static FragmentB newInstance(int id){
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putInt("id", id);
         FragmentB frag = new FragmentB();
         frag.setArguments(args);
     }


    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
       super.onCreate(b);
       this.id = getArguments().getInt("id);
    }

}
```

Comment: The communication works but for some reason the data I pass does not stay.

Comment: Do you use Fragment arguments? Otherwise the data will not be stored!

Comment: Ah thanks, I try with arguments. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The set and get arguments worked great. Thank you. This makes the interface redundant now.

Comment: @Raghunandan Components are not decoupled. Take this example: You have a tablet mail app. You have an Inbox Activity, which consist of 2 fragments: MailListFragment (displays a list of all mails in you inbox) and a MailDetailsFragment (displays the details of the current selected mail). So your with the "bullshit" pattern, your InboxActivity is responsible to take the info from MailListFragment the selection and forward it to the MailDetailsFragment. With an EventBus the middleman (InboxActivity) is not anymore, because MailDetailsFragment receives an MailSelectedEvent and adjusts its view.

Comment: @sockeqwe the problem which op faces has nothing to do with interface call back design pattern. Its left to the user choice. The deisgn pattern is not as bad as you think as Fragments are hosted by the activity itself

Comment: @Raghunandan Things get even more complicated, if you have an ViewPager. The Activity contains a Fragment A and a ViewPager. If you do something in Fragment A and you may want to refresh/ adjust  Fragment B's content the Activity needs to have a reference to Fragment B to tell Fragment B that something has changed. In the current API of ViewPager there is no way to get the current displayed Fragment (I know there are workarounds by using fragment tag/ id). The point is, with an event bus the activity (middleman) is not needed to forward information from Fragment A to Fragment B (in ViewPager)

Comment: @Raghunandan Alright that's true and you are right: "the problem which op faces has nothing to do with interface call back design pattern"
However I think that using an eventbus is a better way and should be mentioned in the android docs. Moreover, you have to cast your Activity to your Interface in the Fragments onAttach() method. Every java developer would slap you if you would do that in a java application, but not so in Android because people are encouraged to do that from the official docs

Answer (score 1):

When you replace Fragment A  by Fragment B.

```
@Override
public void onGameSelectedListener(int gameID, Boolean isCustom) {
  ...// rest of the code
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt("id", gameID);
  args.putBoolean("bool", isCustom);
  FB.setArguments(args);

}
```

In Fragment B

```
int value = getArguments().getInt("id");
```

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, I make a new instance of fragment B after I call the listener. So I should set arguments instead in my newInstance method. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3364963 Fragments have no arg constructor. Well the above also works. the newInstance which the other user posted also works